# Link Redirection is not happening when pass link through deeplink in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying redirect to a specific screen when tap on to the notification in ios in react native using firebase and deeplink but could not do..I am trying to resolve It..And firebase suggests that they could not provide any link for ios..

Please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask